# Modifying a list on a tuple.I get a type error, but the tuple value is changed

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying:

```
>>> a = []
>>> id(a)
42952968L
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>>id(a)
42952968L
>>> a += [2]
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>> id(a)
42952968L
>>> a = a +[3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
43001480L
```

I know the we using `a.append(1)` or `a += [2]`,the `id(a)` is't changing.when using `a = a +[3]` the `id(a)` is changed.

Now , I using like this:

```
>>> c = ([], [])
>>> id(c)
43002440L
>>> c[0].append(1)
>>> c
([1], [])
>>> id(c)
43002440L
>>> c[0] += [2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> c
([1, 2], [])
>>> id(c)
43002440L
```

I using `c[0].append(1)` is right, when I trying `c[0] += [2]`, I got a type error.But I found the `c` value is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c[0] += [2]` happens in multiple steps, roughly equivalent to the following:

```
import operator
x = c[0]
x = operator.iadd(x, [2])
c[0] = x
```

First, Python gets `c[0]`. That part works fine.

The second part may look a bit strange. Python asks the object it got as `c[0]` to add `[2]` to itself in-place. The list `[1]` obliges, becoming `[1, 2]`. A different data type might not implement this in-place, returning a new object. Lists modify themselves and return themselves.

Then, Python tries to assign `[1, 2]` to `c[0]`. This step fails, giving a `TypeError`, but the list has already been modified in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> c[0] += [2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

`tuple`(s) in Python are immutable objects. You therefore cannot modify them.

`c[0]` in this case is a reference to the first item/slot of that tuple which when you attempt to **assign** to it with `+=` fails with the above `TypeError`.

Consider using:

```
c[0].extend([2])
```

The reason `c[0].extend([2])` works is that `c[0]` is a reference to the `list` instance and not a slot of a `tuple`. Modifying it is therefore the same as you would with any `list` reference/variable.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the value is changed anyway.

Comment: Even though this produces a `TypeError`, `c[0]` still shows the attempted change. This answer doesn't explain that.

Comment: You missed the point. After `c[0] += [2]`, `c[0]` is `[1, 2]`.

Comment: You can't do this if ``c[0] is ([1], [])``? What? Are you getting confused or am i? :)

Comment: Run this in the REPL, then look at what `c` is after the error: `c = ([1], []); c[0] += [2]`

Comment: That's very interesting :) I'd call that a bug with CPython (*2.7.6 here*). *sigh* :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
.extend()
```

instead of

```
+=
```